# AWS Elastic Beanstalk logs? Access more detailed logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently deploying a couple of apps with Elastic Beanstalk and have some open questions. One thing that bugs me about EB is the logs. I can run `eb logs` or request the logs from the GUI. But the result is kind of confusing to me since I can't find a way to access the normal stdout for a running process. I'm running a Django app and it seems like the logs automatically show every log that is explicitly set to a Warning priority.

In Django, there are a lot of errors that seem to slip through the log system (e. g. failed migrations, failed custom commands, etc.)

Is there any way to access more detailed logs, or access the `stdout` of my main process? It would also be ok, if they would stream to my terminal, or if I had to ssh on the machine.

Comment: Unless you modified something, `stdout` logs should be in `/var/log/web.stdout.log`. Have you checked that file?

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, the file exists but it does not seem to be connected to any process. So, it has no contents.

Comment: Can you login to the EB instance and check from inside? This is the file which should contain std out from your application.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm not sure what you mean by logging in. I used `eb ssh` to access the ec2 instance and checked out the file with vim. Is there another way?

Comment: `eb ssh` is fine. So the file is totally empty?

Comment: @Marcin yes, completely empty. I‘m running django and I think by default its running in a virtual env. Maybe thats why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [cli to enable the cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html) with `eb logs --cloudwatch-logs enable --cloudwatch-log-source all`. This will allow you to see the streaming output of `web.stdout.log` along with all of your other logs individually.